# Calculating Properties Relative to Other Objects in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use Kivy for the first time. I have imported a function from an external file using

```
#:import centerAlign helperFunctions.centerAlign
```

My function (centerAlign) looks like this:

```
def centerAlign(elem, parent):
    pos = [parent.width/2-elem.width/2, parent.height/2-elem.height/2]
    return pos
```

It's implementation looks like this:

```
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.25
        pos: centerAlign(self, root)
```

This fails because it's calculating a height and width of 100 for both elements (root and GridLayout). However, I know this should be working because when I say:

```
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.25
        pos: [root.width/2-self.width/2, root.height/2-self.height/2]
```

It works great! So I really don't understand what's happening here. I'm a bit new to Python so hopefully it's something simple that a seasoned veteran can shed some light on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pos: [root.width/2-self.width/2, root.height/2-self.height/2]
```

When kv parses this line, it is able to see that it needs to update `pos` when root.width, root.height, self.width or self.height change, because they are all referenced here. Bindings are automatically created to achieve this.

```
 pos: centerAlign(self, root)
```

In this row there aren't any properties to bind to, so there is no update when anything changes. You therefore only get a result based on the initial value of the width/height, which is 100.

To solve this, either reference the properties you want to bind to in the kv line *or* write some other code to create the bindings you want.